# Is there any way to suppress Maven Javadoc Plugin errors when detectLinks is true?

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

If I set property detectLinks for the Maven Javadoc Plugin, some errors are issued for dependencies that do not provide apidocs as assumed by Maven conventions. Is there any way to suppress such errors without setting detectLinks to false and specifying all apidocs links explicitly?

FYI, I already have specified each apidocs location explicitly for such an artifact. So it is OK if I can exclude them from automatic apidocs detection.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to resolve my issue quickly, I decided to make changes to the Maven Javadoc Plugin and to send them back so as to resolve my problem.